# ItextSharp PDFCopy throwing null reference exception

Tags: itext

I'm attempting to merge 2 pdfs, (I'm following the examples in the iText in Action 2nd edition book) and I'm getting a null reference exception error when attempting to run this code:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
document.Open();                                     //breakpoint here
```

The copy object has a null reference exception every time. I've been unable to find a simple answer to this anywhere else on this site. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace? And which iTextSharp version to you use?

Comment: This was a problem in iTextSharp 5.3.4; it was fixed in iTextSharp 5.3.5.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833285/pdfwriter-getinstance-throws-system-nullreferenceexception), you have to ignore this exception.  I am getting the same exception in iTextSharp 5.5.2.  By simply ignoring it, I am able to proceed in my code and copy pages into a new pdf file alright.

Comment: well fu me, this saved my day. I am using iTextSharp 5.5