# PdfWriter.GetInstance throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, itext

I'm trying to create a pdf document using iTextSharp 5.3.4 using the following

```
Document document = new Document();
FileStream stm = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stm);
```

I'm getting a System.NullReferenceException with the following stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
HResult=-2147467261
Message=La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
Source=itextsharp
StackTrace:
   à iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance()
InnerException:
```

I've verified that neither document nor stm are null, and if I select "continue" in VS12 the document is created - however the exception is always thrown.
I updated to iTextSharp 5.4.0 and it's still occurring.
I can't find any information on this anywhere - anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

Make sure you are not catching all exceptions. This `NullReferenceException` can very well be one that is already caught and handled inside iTextSharp, so you don't care about it.
The fact that you can continue supports this theory.

Change the following setting to verify:

Debug -> Exceptions -> Remove the checkbox in the column "Thrown" of "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Comment: I took the PdfWriter.GetInstance() out of the try/catch block, but it's still throwing the exception... having said that, it only crashes the app when I run it in VS12 - running it outside VS12 is OK!

Comment: @Hoverfrog: That's just the effect I am describing. Please read my answer again, thoroughly. Your application isn't crashing. The debugger merely shows you an exception. That exception however is caught by iTextSharp afterwards, so *you don't care about it*

Comment: "Debug -> Exceptions -> Remove the checkbox in the column "Thrown" of "Common Language Runtime Exceptions""

Comment: sorry - pressed return for a newline and it posted! Was trying to say:- "Debug -> Exceptions -> Remove the checkbox in the column "Thrown" of "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"" - I did that, the app crashes - "first chance exception in iText.dll". I can no longer run this functionality from within VS12 (well not without breaking on the exception and pressing continue!), however it does not appear to crash when run outside of the IDE. At least after reading your comment I thought to try it outside of VS12 :)

Comment: Well, I feel so lucky finding this answer. While fixing another bug I had previously enabled this Exception setting. Disabling it solved the problem with throwing NullPointerException from PdfWriter.GetInstance() .. Thx Daniel.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019+, using CTRL+ALT+E will open the Exception Settings, allowing you to uncheck the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in the "Break When Thrown" column

Answer (score -1):

After long debugging, I found a curious solution that works.
It is based on a discovery: the PdtWriter instance seems to be created in a long time, then a delay solve the problem.
Here I propose my solution: a function that returns a PdfWriter instance.

```
static  public iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter   PdfWriter_GetInstance(iTextSharp.text.Document document , System.IO.FileStream FS )
{
  iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = null;
           
  for (int Times = 0; Times < 6; Times++)
  {
    try
    {
      writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, FS); // sometime rise exception on first call
      break; //created, then exit loop
    }
    catch
    {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); // wait for a while...
    }
  }
  if (writer == null) // check if instantiated
  {
    throw new Exception("iTextSharp PdfWriter is null");
  }
            
  return writer;
}
```

Comment: Noup, still throwing an exception.

Comment: Not working, the problem still persists. PdfWriter.GetInstance null exception is still uncaught...