# iText Sharp Exception

Tags: c#, itext

I added a new form to a winforms app and now I am getting an exception in the iTextSharp.Core Version.cs code file in the GetInstance() method.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("iTextSharp.license.LicenseKey, itextsharp.LicenseKey");
MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("GetLicenseeInfo");
```

It's showing type as null. It's never done this before, so I have no idea why it's doing it now.

Comment: I found my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833285/pdfwriter-getinstance-throws-system-nullreferenceexception

Comment: Rather than commenting on your question, it would be better to answer it yourself. Otherwise, foolish people like me might not see this important info straight away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer here: [PdfWriter.GetInstance throws System.NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833285/pdfwriter-getinstance-throws-system-nullreferenceexception)

I was catching all thrown exceptions:

Debug -> Exceptions -> Remove the checkbox in the column "Thrown" of "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Answer (score 0):

Check upper/lower cases.

For example it is not

```
MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("GetLicenseeInfo");
```

but

```
MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("GetLicenseInfo");
```

Comment: I have changed nothing from the original code. I have even downloaded the latest version of iTextSharp and get the same exception. Those lines of code are from the iTextSharp code. The exception is actually that the "type" variable is null and fails on the line after, which means it's not able to load that type for some reason.

Comment: If that type is null, could it be that you unintentionally removed the license key from your project?

Comment: or missing a reference/library? (e.g. itextsharp.licensekey.dll)