# Itext7 cleanup method throws error - Index was out of range

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, itext, itext7

I am getting the below error while trying to redact pdf document using itext7

I am calling pdfCleanupTool.cleanup() method for redaction and sometimes I am getting the below error from the cleanup method:

**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index**

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

**Updates:**

Error Log:

[image]

Comment: Please share an example pdf to reproduce the issue with.

Comment: @mkl sorry, but, it's a client document. not able to share. but, the issue happens when I have applied redaction for specific text and then trying to apply using itext.

Comment: Then please try to find another document which you can share for which cleanup fails identically. If you cannot find such a document, chances are that an error in the PDF at hand is the cause of the error. The least you can do is supply a complete stacktrace of the error. With some luck, that stacktrace hints at the cause of the issue.

Comment: @mkl updated error log as you suggested

Comment: At first glance at the sources that shouldn't happen. Which version do you use exactly, maybe that's something already fixed...

Comment: Ah, I found a possible cause. That would be an iText error, though.

Comment: @mkl it's pdfsweep 2.0.5 & itext7 7.0.10 version

Comment: The answer was posted here on StackOverFlow:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442158/itextsharp-pdfcopy-throwing-null-reference-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442158/itextsharp-pdfcopy-throwing-null-reference-exception)

Comment: The answer was posted here on StackOverFlow:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442158/itextsharp-pdfcopy-throwing-null-reference-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442158/itextsharp-pdfcopy-throwing-null-reference-exception)

Answer (score 0):

*There is a bug in the iText 7 `PdfTextArray` class which generates stack traces like yours. As you don't share your PDF, though, I cannot be sure whether that's the bug bothering you currently.*

#### The Bug

The bug can be provoked quite easily, in Java like this

```java
PdfTextArray textArray = new PdfTextArray();
textArray.add(1);
textArray.add(-1);
textArray.add(1);
```

*([CancelingAdjustments](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/cleanup/CancelingAdjustments.java) test `testCancelingAdjustments`)*

and similarly in C#.

This essentially may be what happens in the OP's case; redaction involves removal of text pieces from such text arrays and replacement by equivalent numeric adjustments, so such situations may be more probable during redaction than in general.

#### The Cause

When adding multiple numbers to a `PdfTextArray`, it attempts to combine them to a single number, and if that single number is zero, remove it altogether:

```java
public boolean add(float number) {
    // adding zero doesn't modify the TextArray at all
    if (number != 0) {
        if (!Float.isNaN(lastNumber)) {
            lastNumber = number + lastNumber;
            if (lastNumber != 0) {
                set(size() - 1, new PdfNumber(lastNumber));
            } else {
                remove(size() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            lastNumber = number;
            super.add(new PdfNumber(lastNumber));
        }
        lastString = null;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*(PdfTextArray method `add`)*

But this code forgets to reset the `lastNumber` variable to "not a number" after removal due to cancelation. Thus, this bug can be fixed like this:

```java
public boolean add(float number) {
    // adding zero doesn't modify the TextArray at all
    if (number != 0) {
        if (!Float.isNaN(lastNumber)) {
            lastNumber = number + lastNumber;
            if (lastNumber != 0) {
                set(size() - 1, new PdfNumber(lastNumber));
            } else {
                remove(size() - 1);
                lastNumber = Float.NaN;
            }
        } else {
            lastNumber = number;
            super.add(new PdfNumber(lastNumber));
        }
        lastString = null;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(One could improve this some more by testing whether there is some string at the now last position of the array and initialize `lastString` accordingly.)

The iText/.Net code is very similar here.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but, it's part of itext7 side. so, how can I use/change it?

Comment: Well, iText 7 is open source, so you can fix the issue in the code, compile iText, and used your compiled version. Or you can wait a bit until this issue is fixed in the "official" iText distribution.

Comment: I just see, though, that you are using 7.0.10. The fix in the official distribution will likely only be in the next 7.1.x to come. Thus, you might have to update your other code a bit.

Comment: so, I won't be able to solve this issue. till new release come. right?

Comment: First of all, as you didn't share your pdf, I cannot be sure whether the issue i found is the issue causing your problem. The stack traces merely are similar enough that it might be. But you can test by fixing and compiling itext yourself as described in my answer. Thus, if the issue i found is causing your problem, you can quickly solve the issue.

Comment: actually the problem is itext7 is closed source. so I can't make any changes to it. I can only  use what they will provide.

Comment: *"itext7 is closed source"* - whoever told you so is ill-informed. Just point your browser to https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet and you see the sources. Thus, you're wrong assuming you *can only use what they will provide.*

Comment: @DivyangShah Did fixing the explained error resolve your problem?